# I'm trying to figure out a way to have an inputstream from one class be parsed in a different class

Tags: android, dom, inputstream, http-post, xml-parsing

I am fairly new to Android and I like to have an inputstream be transferred from one class to another.
Basically, I am trying to get a geocoded location to be sent to a server and a response to be sent to the other class for parsing.

here is a snippet of code I have so far for the httppost and inputstream response:

Location1.java

```
private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {
  if (location != null) {
    double lat = location.getLatitude();
    String lat1 = Double.toString(lat);
    double lng = location.getLongitude();
    String lng1 = Double.toString(lng);

 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://...");

 try {

     List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
```

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", lat1));
         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng", lng1));
         httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

```
     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
 InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
```

BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
   ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(20);

```
int current = 0;  
while((current = bis.read()) != -1){  
 baf.append((byte)current);  
}
```

Here is a snippet from the other class I want to have the inputstream parsed in... There already was an inputsream in this class and I was trying to figure out how to replace it with the other stream from the other class.

parser1.java

```
       //I already have an inputstream here and this is where I want to inject the other class inputstream

          InputStream in = httpConnection.getInputStream(); 
          DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

   // parse the feed
   Document dom = db.parse(in);      
   Element docEle = dom.getDocumentElement(); ...
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is more a `Java` question than an Android one.  Can't you just make your existing `updateWithNewLocation()` method `public` and return an `InputStream` rather than `void`?  Something like:

Location1.java

```
public static InputStream updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {
    InputStream result = null;
    if (location != null) {
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        String lat1 = Double.toString(lat);
        double lng = location.getLongitude();
        String lng1 = Double.toString(lng);

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://...");

        try {

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", lat1));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng", lng1));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            result = response.getEntity().getContent();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            //error handling
        }
    return result;
}
```

parser1.java

```
...
InputStream in = Location1.updateWithNewLocation(location)
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

// parse the feed
Document dom = db.parse(in);      
Element docEle = dom.getDocumentElement();
...
```